# Prove that $SO_2$ is a normal subgroup of $O_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been working on this for a few days. I can show the conditions that $SO_2$ is a group, but I cannot show the normal subgroup condition.

Comment: The determinant map $\det: O(n)\to\{-1,1\}$ is an epimorphism whose kernel is the subset of $O(n)$ with determinant $1$. $\{-1,1\}$ is regarded as a group under multiplication, so the identity element is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The kernel of the determinant restricted to $O(2)$ is $SO(2)$